# Combining two dictionaries where dictionary one key is range of integers and second dictionary keys are integers that may fall into first key's range

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, range

fairly new to `Python3`.

I have two dictionaries constructed from two separate `CSV` files.

The first dictionary looks like something along the lines of:

```
dict_FET = {2658451: "6.67e-05", 2565843: "1.513-05", etc....}
```

The second dictionary is a similar key; value pairing, but keys are a range of integers.

```
dict_FST = {range(2500000, 2600000): '0.924', range(2600000, 2800000): '.0694', etc..}
```

I am looking to combine values from both dictionaries into an array, keeping the key from the first dictionary. So in the example above, the dictionary I would like would look like:

```
dict_combined = {2565843: ['1.513e-05', '0.694'], 2658451: [6.67e-05,'0.924',], etc....
```

I think I would need to construct a loop, and have tried something along the lines of

```
dict_combined = {k: [dict_FET.get(k), dict_FST.get(k)] for k in keys if keys in range dict_FST.keys()}
```

The syntax is obviously incorrect, but am I one the right path here?

Comment: Your desired results don't make sense. Either the ranges are an order of magnitude too small, or the keys of `dict_FET` are that much too big—in other words none of keys in the first dictionary are in the ranges shown in the second.

Comment: Ah good catch, I was off by a factor of ten in the example dictionary. I just made these values up as an example, the real dictionary keys are expected to be found in the ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most efficient way I could conceive. A dictionary comprehension doesn't seem feasible given the way you want the data collected, so it takes a few more lines to accomplish.

```
dict_FET = {2658451: "6.67e-05", 2565843: '1.513e-05'}
# Note: The following range values were scaled by 10x so there would be results.
dict_FST = {range(2500000, 2600000): '0.924', range(2600000, 2800000): '.0694'}

dict_combined = {}
for key, value1 in dict_FET.items():
    dict_combined.setdefault(key, [value1]).extend(
        value2 for interval, value2 in dict_FST.items() if key in interval)

print(dict_combined)
```

Output:

```
{2658451: ['6.67e-05', '.0694'], 2565843: ['1.513e-05', '0.924']}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment, this worked well.  As a follow-up question to your answer, does the .setdefault() method ensure that keys in dict_FET that do not fit into a given range are still put into dict_combined with only one value, or would I need to add an 'else' clause to handle that scenario?

Comment: Matthew: Yes, it will put key in `dict_combined` for each of the ones that exist in `dict_FET`, regardless of whether there are any matches based on the range values in `dict_FST`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was asking. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as this?

```
dict_combined = { k:[v,dict_FST[k] ] for k,v in dict_FET}
```

I do not quite get your comment about equal spacing of the indexes in `dict_FST` though, as ranges() are generators. You can save them as keys, but i do not belive this what you really depict here.

Assuming that your second dictionary is sparse populated, aka it has only some of the integer keys in the range(x,y) and you want to pair up on the first match, the thing will get more complicated.

Comment: With this code I receive a "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)".

Comment: I meant that each key had a different range of values, steps was not the best phrasing.  So one range might encompass 1000 integers, the next 600, the next 800, and so on. I didn't know if it was relevant information but I included it. I've removed it for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Simple for loop is sometimes the best option.

```
dict_FET = {2658451: "6.67e-05", 2565843: "1.513-05"}
dict_FST = {range(2500000, 2600000): '0.924', range(2600000, 2800000): '.0694'}
dict_combined = {}

for fet_k, fet_v in dict_FET.items():
    for fst_k, fst_v in dict_FST.items():
        if fet_k in fst_k:
            dict_combined[fet_k] = [fet_v, fst_v]

print(dict_combined)
```

(note I tenfolded the ranges)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off with writing for loops than dictionary comprehensions in these situations but anyway:

```
dict_FET = {265845: '6.67e-05', 256584: '1.513-05'}    # note I edit the keys
dict_FST = {range(250000, 260000): '0.924', range(260000, 280000): '.0694'}

a = list(dict_FST.keys())[0]

# k and v are key and value of dict_FET 
# ik and iv are key and value of dict_FST 
comb = {k : [v, *[iv for ik, iv in dict_FST.items() if k in ik]] for k,v in dict_FET.items()}
print(comb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

```
dict_FET = { 2658451: "6.67e-05", 2565843: '1.513-05'}
dict_FST = { range(2500000, 2600000): '0.924', range(2600000, 2800000): '.0694'}   
from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in dict_FET.items():
    v1 = [j for i, j in dict_FST.items() if k in i]
    d_dict[k].append(v)
    d_dict[k].extend(v1)

dict(d_dict)
```

Output:

```
{2565843: ['1.513-05', '0.924'], 2658451: ['6.67e-05', '.0694']}
```

Comment: I checked this solution in addition to the one provided by martineau and this solution also provided the desired output. Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Thanks, if you find this answer useful in anyway, you can always upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that all the ranges are non-overlapping you could try this

```
dict_FET = {2658451: "6.67e-05", 2565843: '1.513-05'}
dict_FST = {(2500000, 2600000): '0.924', (2600000, 2800000): '.0694'}
dict_combined = {k: [v1, v2] 
                 for k, v1 in dict_FET.items() 
                 for (l, r), v2 in dict_FST.items() if l <= k < r}
```

(Note, I've changed the keys to tuples instead of ranges, I think it's simpler, also adapted the ranges for the example)